# Restart the existing perl script using $^X in a list context when it contains spaces

Tags: windows, perl

I am running a program that I would periodically like to restart.  I prefer to pass exec a list so that the shell is not involved as follows:

```
    // Do stuff 
    .
    .
    exec $^X, $0, @ARGV;
```

When I do this (on Windows) and $^X contains spaces using the above it treats $^X as multiple items and fails.

The following works just fine, but starts a subshell in addition to the script:

```
    # Do stuff 
    .
    .
    exec "\"$^X\" $0 @ARGV" ;
```

This is not a huge deal, but I would like to learn how to execute in a list context if possible.

Things I have tried:

```
    exec "\"$^X\"", $0, @ARGV;
    exec "\\\"$^X\\\"", $0, @ARGV;
    exec "'$^X'", $0, @ARGV;  # Even though Windows doesn't like '
```

Also:

```
    push @restart, $^X, $0, @ARGV;
    print $restart[0];
    exec @restart;
```

The print statement correctly shows the executable with the space in it as the first item in the array.

I have copied the perl executable to a location that does not contain spaces in its path and from there exec given a list works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows files have a regular name and a "short" name for backwards compatibility with the golden age of DOS. For the specific case of `$^X = 'C:\Program Files\perl\perl.exe`, something like `C:/Progra~1/perl/perl.exe` would probably work.

For a more general solution, see the [`Win32`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32) and the `GetShortPathName` function. Then you could call

```
exec Win32::GetShortPathName($^X), $0, @args;
```

(in some cases you may want to wrap `$0` and the arguments in `GetShortPathName`, too).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
exec $^X $0, @ARVG
```

Note, no comma after the first argument.  If it works, consult [`perldoc -f exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) for the reason why there is special syntax for `exec PROGRAM LIST`.

Comment: That does not work for me.  I was not clear enough in the explanation above.  The string returned by $^X contains a space: C:\Program Files\perl\perl.exe.  The exec interprets C:\Program as the program name and Files\perl\perl.exe as the first parameter to it.  I can only get it to work by having exec run in a scalar context which invokes a new command interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot pass arguments to Windows program, just a command line. (Yeah, that's awful.) Combined with oddities in both Perl and in Window's `CreateProcess`, we get all kinds of curious behaviour.

I'm not on Windows at the moment, but I think you can get it to work with:

```
exec { $^X } "perl", $0, @ARVG
```